# How to write SQL in this situation?

Tags: mysql, sql

Table comment contains comment and its replies

```
CREATE TABLE `comment` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `comment` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Table `reply_to` which has `response_id` and `comment_id` 
both of which are the IDs of the records in the comment table.

```
CREATE TABLE `reply_to` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `response_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  `comment_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

If table comment has data like the following:
[image]

And table reply_to contains
[image]

And expected result like :
[image]

**Question:** How can I display all comments and their replies by using a left outer join?

This question came out from this page

> [Database design for comments and replies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490609/database-design-for-comments-and-replies)
>   How come the sql below not working here ?

```
 SELECT c.comment, r.comment as reply
 FROM Comment c 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Comment r on c.id = r.id  
 LEFT OUTER JOIN reply_to rt on rt.response_id = r.id
```

Comment: Add a tag of your DBMS

Comment: Expected output would also be helpful.

Comment: Even better than "expected output" : an ***explanation*** of what it ***means*** to be both "response_to" 2 as well as "comment_id" 1 ...

Comment: Go on. Try something

Comment: This feels like a homework assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still not totally clear what you want the results to look like, but the original query (the one with ANSI-89 joins) from the post you linked to gives the results I expected:

[image]

So I rewrote that query with proper joins, and it looks like this:

```
SELECT
    oc.comment,
    rc.comment
FROM
    comment oc
INNER JOIN
    reply_to r
    ON r.comment_id = oc.id
INNER JOIN
    comment rc
    ON r.response_id = rc.id
```

If you want to see comments with no reply:

[image]

then you could use left outer joins like this:

```
SELECT
    oc.comment,
    rc.comment
FROM
    comment oc
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    reply_to r
    ON r.comment_id = oc.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    comment rc
    ON r.response_id = rc.id
```